# Swift forget objects is a type

Tags: swift, protocols

When looping though a an array of UICollectionViewCells in UICollectionView.visibleCells() then checking if the cell conforms to a protocol, it forgets that the cell is a UIView and has a frame property.

```
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells() {

    let cellPosition1 = cell.frame.origin
    if let cell = cell as? AwesomeCellProtocol {

        let cellPosition2 = cell.frame.origin

        cell.doAwesome(cellPosition)
    }
}
```

Swift give a compile error on setting cellPosition2:

```
Value of type 'AwesomeCellProtocol' has no member 'frame'
```

Setting cellPosition1 works fine.

Can I check for both UIView and AwesomeCellProtocol?

Comment: You cannot currently create a mix of class type and protocol type like you could in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
if let cell = cell as? AwesomeCellProtocol { ... }
```

you introduce a new variable `cell` for the scope of the if-block,
which "shadows" the `cell` variable from the outer scope of the for-loop.
That local variable has the type `AwesomeCellProtocol` and not 
`UICollectionViewCell`.

You can avoid that problem by binding to a different name:

```
if let awesomeCell = cell as? AwesomeCellProtocol {

    let cellPosition2 = cell.frame.origin
    awesomeCell.doAwesome(cellPosition)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you unwrap the optional, you are correct that it is no longer the Type you expect, but rather `objectWithAwesomeCellProtocol` .

If you want to keep it as a UICollectionViewCell instead, you could try using `is` instead of `as?`, but then you'd need to handle `nil` cases yourself.

From Apple's Swift Programming Language Guide under ["Checking for Protocol Conformance"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

> You can use the `is` and `as` operators described in Type Casting to check for protocol conformance, and to cast to a specific protocol.
>
> The `is` operator returns `true` if an instance conforms to a protocol and returns `false` if it does not.
>
> The `as?` version of the downcast operator returns an optional value of the protocol’s type, and this value is `nil` if the instance does not conform to that protocol.
>
> Note that the underlying objects are not changed by the casting process ... However, at the point that they are stored in the [unwrapped optional] constant, they are only known to be of type [protocol], and so only their [protocol-specific] property can be accessed.

Comment: I would have picked this because using 'is' would work but in my case i need to refer to the cell as both UIView and AwesomeCellProtocol, not just check for them, thank you anyway.